# Cannot delete Feature Class, after having un-registered as versioned. The item does not have a definition

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.7

On our ArcGIS 10.7.1, we tried to unregister a Feature Class as not longer versioned. After this was done, we are unable to open the Feature Class:

[image]

We are also not able to re-register the Feature Class as versioned, again:

[image]

Our database is a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP2.

We also tried to delete the Feature Class, which gave the below error:

[image]

Any idea, of how we can get this Feature Class removed, so we can re-create it?

I have tried the following:

- Diagnose Version Metadata
- Diagnose Table Versions

None of these found any errors.

Comment: Often the issue is that the table *has* been deleted, but the metadata still exists in geodatabase XML. The solution is to create a new empty table via SQL, then delete it again via ArcObjects (ArcGIS clients).

Comment: Hello Vince,
Unfortunately, the table still exists on the SQL server. I can also make a select in SQL, and get the data. Just not in ArcMap/from ESRI tools.

Comment: Right. So then we come to the "What was changed?" question. Columns? Ownership? Permissions? This is more an issue for Tech Support, since there's a litany of other troubleshooting questions.

Comment: The only thing changed was that we right-clicked on the Feature Class and selected "unregister as versioned." After this, it gave the above issue, and we are unable to do _anything_ with it.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade your geodatabase and/or the version of ArcGIS you use? I have encountered this error when interacting with an enterprise geodatabase table from an older client library. For example, a table with attribute rules (ArcGIS Pro functionality) from ArcCatalog 10.7.1.